# Save screenshot of control to clipboard

Tags: uwp

I'm trying to copy a screenshot (bitmap) of a UWP UIElement to the clipboard, suitable for pasting into e.g. Paint.

Here's what I have so far:

```
        public async void CopyScreenshot(UIElement content)
        {
            DataPackage dataPackage = new();

            using (InMemoryRandomAccessStream stream = new())
            {
                await RenderContentToRasterStreamAsync(content, stream);
                stream.Seek(0);    
                
                dataPackage.SetBitmap(RandomAccessStreamReference.CreateFromStream(stream));  
            }

            try
            {
                Clipboard.SetContent(dataPackage);
                Data.AppStatusText = "Screenshot copied to clipboard.";
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                Data.AppStatusText = "Copying to clipboard failed.";
            }
        }

        private async Task RenderContentToRasterStreamAsync(UIElement content, IRandomAccessStream stream)
        {
            RenderTargetBitmap renderTargetBitmap = new();
            await renderTargetBitmap.RenderAsync(content);

            var pixelBuffer = await renderTargetBitmap.GetPixelsAsync();
            var pixels = pixelBuffer.ToArray();
            var displayInformation = DisplayInformation.GetForCurrentView();

            var encoder = await BitmapEncoder.CreateAsync(BitmapEncoder.PngEncoderId, stream);
            encoder.SetPixelData(BitmapPixelFormat.Bgra8,
                BitmapAlphaMode.Premultiplied,
                (uint)renderTargetBitmap.PixelWidth,
                (uint)renderTargetBitmap.PixelHeight,
                displayInformation.RawDpiX,
                displayInformation.RawDpiY,
                pixels);

            await encoder.FlushAsync();
        }
```

This code runs, but when attempting to paste the result I get the message:

"The information on the clipboard cannot be inserted into Paint".

The `RenderContentToRasterStreamAsync` method works as desired when I use it to save a picture of the UIElement to a file.

What do I need to change to copy to the clipboard? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Save screenshot of control to clipboard

Derive testing, it looks the stream comes from  `RenderContentToRasterStreamAsync` has been closed before insert into the data package. During testing with official [code sample](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/blob/master/Samples/Clipboard/cs/CopyImage.xaml.cs), it could copy and pause image for Paint. Base on this thread, I have edited `RenderContentToRasterStreamAsync1` thread and make the stream as return, then load it as bitmap. haha, It woks!

```
public async void CopyScreenshot1(UIElement content)
{
    DataPackage dataPackage = new DataPackage();
    var stream = await RenderContentToRasterStreamAsync1(content);
    dataPackage.SetBitmap(RandomAccessStreamReference.CreateFromStream(stream));

    try
    {
        Clipboard.SetContent(dataPackage);

    }
    catch (Exception)
    {

    }
}

private async Task<InMemoryRandomAccessStream> RenderContentToRasterStreamAsync1(UIElement content)
{
    RenderTargetBitmap renderTargetBitmap = new RenderTargetBitmap();
    await renderTargetBitmap.RenderAsync(content);

    var pixelBuffer = await renderTargetBitmap.GetPixelsAsync();
    var pixels = pixelBuffer.ToArray();
    var displayInformation = DisplayInformation.GetForCurrentView();

    var stream = new InMemoryRandomAccessStream();
    var encoder = await BitmapEncoder.CreateAsync(BitmapEncoder.PngEncoderId, stream);
    encoder.SetPixelData(BitmapPixelFormat.Bgra8,
        BitmapAlphaMode.Premultiplied,
        (uint)renderTargetBitmap.PixelWidth,
        (uint)renderTargetBitmap.PixelHeight,
        displayInformation.RawDpiX,
        displayInformation.RawDpiY,
        pixels);

    await encoder.FlushAsync();

    return stream;
}
```